# BindValue Error Using Cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent, android-sqlite

i want to send Data With Intent To Another Activity For Use In Cursor But i my Way Dont Work

Main Activity :

```
int classId = classData.get(position).getClassId();
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(getActivity() , StudentList.class);
    intent.putExtra("classId" , classId);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Target Activity :

```
int classId = getIntent().getIntExtra("classId" , 0);

             List<StudentTable> tableData = new ArrayList<>();

             Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select * from " + tblName_Student + " where class_id = ?",
                  new String[classId]);
             close();

             while (cursor.moveToNext())
             {
             StudentTable table = new StudentTable();

             table.setStudentName(cursor.getString(2));

             tableData.add(table);
             }
```

LogCat Error :

```
03-06 17:41:53.274 11676-11676/com.example.user.classmanager     E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.user.classmanager, PID: 11676
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activityComponentInfo{com.example.user.classmanager/com.example.user.classmanager.StudentList}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 2 is null
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 2 is null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your issue is with the following code:-

```
         Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select * from " + tblName_Student + " where class_id = ?",
              new String[classId]);
         close();
```

This is passing/using an uninitialiased array with the number of elements equating to the value of classId. All elements are null as none have been initialised with any values.

Instead you should be passing an array with a single element, initialised with the value of classId. The following should do that :-

```
         Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select * from " + tblName_Student + " where class_id = ?",
              new String[]{String.valueOf(classId)}); //<<<<< declare and initialise a String array with 1 element.
         close();
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much , Your response helped me a lot @MikeT

Comment: @NimaKhalili, if this answered your question then please mark the question as answered.